# How can i toggle the same button click event for two cases?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void btnRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FFmpeg_Capture record = new FFmpeg_Capture();
            record.Start("Testing", 60);
        }
```

What i want to do is when i click the button it will change the text of it to "Stop" then when i click again it will do the code :

```
record.Stop();
```

and will change the text of the button back to "Record" so i can use the same button to start/stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way may be to introduce the flag which will store the current player state. For just a play/stop this flag may be `bool`, for more states e.g. play/pause/stop it may be `enum`. Then you can use this flag to determine the current state and change it accordingly

```
bool playing = false;
FFmpeg_Capture record = new FFmpeg_Capture();

private void btnRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(playing)
    {
        record.Stop();
        playing = false;
        btnRecord.Text = "Play";
    }
    else
    {
        record.Start("Testing", 60);
        btnRecord.Text = "Stop";
        playing = true;
    }
}
```

The problem here that you may have other ways to change player's state (for example, by click on the player itself) and thus you will need to maintain the `playing` flag in all such a places to be in sync with real player state.

So, the better way will be to check the player itself for state (if the player has such an API). I assumed that player has the `State` property which is enum and this property represtnts the current state. In this case the code may be following. I do not know if the real player has such a property or not, so this is just a idea.

```
FFmpeg_Capture record = new FFmpeg_Capture();
private void btnRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(record.State is CaptureState.Playing)
    {
        record.Stop();
        btnRecord.Text = "Play";
    }
    else
    {
        record.Start("Testing", 60);
        btnRecord.Text = "Stop";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a bool for the current button state.

```
if(button_state)
{
    FFmpeg_Capture record = new FFmpeg_Capture();
    record.Start("Testing", 60);
    button_state != button_state;
    btnRecord.Text = "Stop";
}
else
{
    record.Stop();
    btnRecord.Text = "Record"
    button_state != button_state;
}
```